# ERROR Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, web

**I want to get value from my SQL and then show it to my view and still getting error could not be converted to int**

```
public function v_tambah_barang_dipinjam() {
    $nama_barang['nb'] = $this->input->post('nama_barang');
    $jsa = $this->db->query("SELECT jumlah_barang FROM stok WHERE nama_barang='$nama_barang'");
    $data['stok'] = $this->M_admin->lihat_barang()->result();
    $this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam', $data + $nama_barang + $jsa);
}
```

Comment: format your code so its readable please

Comment: i want to get value of this query on my controller                                   .                 .                                                                                                                                                                                                      $jsa = $this->db->query("SELECT jumlah_barang FROM stok WHERE nama_barang='$nama_barang'");

Comment: and then throw it to myview

Comment: $this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam',$jsa);

Comment: Please show the code for your view.

Comment: <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="total_stok" 
    value="<?php echo $jsa?>" readonly>

Comment: its my code view,

Comment: what kind of result you want trying to expected for your `$jsa` ? 
your code still in query quque, not in any result

Comment: yes, im trying to get value of my SQL and still getting error.. and my target is get value and post to my view

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to add your mysqli result object `$jsa` on this line so php is trying to convert it to an int.

```
 $this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam', $data + $nama_barang + $jsa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `$data` only. And this is invalid `$data + $nama_barang + $jsa`
. You cannot add this because `$data` is not an `int`.

**Change your code from this:**

```
  $this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam', $data + $nama_barang + $jsa);
```

**To this:**

```
$this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam', $data);
```

**Whole Code**

```
public function v_tambah_barang_dipinjam() {
    $nama_barang['nb'] = $this->input->post('nama_barang');
    $jsa = $this->db->query("SELECT jumlah_barang FROM stok WHERE nama_barang='$nama_barang'")->result();

    //This will check first if $jsa is empty
    if(!empty($jsa)){
        $jsa = $jsa[0]->jumlah_barang;
    }else{
        $jsa = '';
    }
    $data['stok'] = $this->M_admin->lihat_barang()->result();
    $data['nama_barang'] = $nama_barang;
    $data['jsa'] = $jsa;
    $this->load->view('v_tambah_barang_dipinjam', $data);
}
```

Just call `$nama_barang` `$jsa` in your `view`

Comment: $nama_barang now is clear but $jsa still error in my view

Comment: <?php echo $jsa?>

Comment: Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: I've edited the answer `$jsa = $this->db->query("SELECT jumlah_barang FROM stok WHERE nama_barang='$nama_barang'")->result();`

By the way are you looping this $jsa?

Comment: $jsa in my view now is empty, no result?? why? but $nama_barang is ok in my view.. iam not looping $jsa... i just want to show $jsa in my view

Comment: $jsa just single row di my database.

Comment: So there will be one result only for $jsa?

Comment: I updated my answer. I add this //This will check first if $jsa is empty
    `if(!empty($jsa)){
        $jsa = $jsa[0]->jumlah_barang;
    }else{
        $jsa = '';
    }`.Please see my updated answer whole code

Comment: You're welcome. Just upvote my answer and accept it as an answer :)